# Aligning dropdown menu

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdown menus in my nav toolbar. The two dropdown menus are: Irish Craft Beers and International beers. When I click either one, the dropdown menu is the same for Irish Craft Beers and International Beers. How do I differentiate between two of them, e.g. International Beers should use the International beers dropdown menu. The second issue is that the dropdown menu moves to the left rather than dropping down directly under the menu. I would like the Irish Craft Beers dropdown menu to be under the Irish Craft Beers menu when selected. I would like the same for International Beers.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/Stylesheet1.css"/>


<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div class="page-header">
                <p class="text-center">
                <asp:Image ID="logo" runat="server" Height="124px" Width="376px" ImageUrl="~/images/logo.jpg"/></p>
                <p class="text-center">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Beers, Loads of them !!!!!!"></asp:Label></p>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown text-center">
              <a href="index.aspx" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" role="button">Home</a> 
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-lg" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                Irish Craft Beers

                <!-- Display icon in button -->
                <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                <!-- Unselectable header -->
                <li class="dropdown-header">Ales</li>
                <li><a href="#">Amber Ale</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Brown Ale</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Red Ale</a></li>

                <!-- Seperates content in menu -->
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Classics</li>

                <!-- Disable menu element -->
                <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Porter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stout</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lager</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Rye</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gluten-Free</a></li>
              </ul>
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-lg" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                International Beers

                <!-- Display icon in button -->
                <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                <!-- Unselectable header -->
                <li class="dropdown-header">European</li>
                <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Danish</a></li>

                <!-- Seperates content in menu -->
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Worldwide</li>

                <!-- Disable menu element -->
                <li class="disabled"><a href="#">American</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Australian</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Asian</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Russian</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
              </ul>
              <a href="specials.aspx" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" role="button">Specials</a>
              <a href="gifts.aspx" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" role="button">Gifts</a>
              <a href="homebrew.aspx" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" role="button">Home Brew Kits</a>
              <a href="contactus.aspx" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" role="button">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
       </header>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`dropdown-toggle` and `dropdown-menu` have to inside `<div class="btn-group">...</div>`

You can follow my codepen: https://codepen.io/hieunguyen135/pen/BJwVaQ